# Using USB as bootable disk but not showing any "install from using usb" option

Tags: installation, live-usb

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 using usb pendrive.

I have made USB bootable. Setup starts but it's not showing "install from USB" option.
It shows only "Install Ubuntu".

Answer (score 4):

**"Install Ubuntu" option there means, Install from USB, since you booted from USB.**

There is no custom messages for CD and USB. All contain "Install Ubuntu" option. The other option is "Try Ubuntu" which Starts Ubuntu without installing giving you a chance to experiment with Ubuntu

Hope this will help.